# Qt Creator error code -1073741819

Tags: c++, qt, mingw, qt-creator

Ok, so have Qt Creator and I tried creating just the most basic application, under Projects->Applications->Qt Gui Applications. The project was successfully created. Furthermore, when I compiled it, it appeared to work just fine.

```
11:07:38: Running steps for project Test1...
11:07:38: Configuration unchanged, skipping qmake step.
11:07:38: Starting: "C:\MinGW\bin\mingw32-make.exe" 
C:/MinGW/bin/mingw32-make -f Makefile.Debug
mingw32-make[1]: Entering directory 'C:/Users/User/CProjects/Test1-build-Windows7Desktop-Debug'
mingw32-make[1]: Nothing to be done for 'first'.
mingw32-make[1]: Leaving directory 'C:/Users/User/CProjects/Test1-build-Windows7Desktop-Debug'
11:07:39: The process "C:\MinGW\bin\mingw32-make.exe" exited normally.
```

However, when I attempt to run it, I get this:

```
Starting C:\Users\User\CProjects\Test1-build-Windows7Desktop-Debug\debug\Test1.exe...
The program has unexpectedly finished.
C:\Users\Hunter\User\Test1-build-Windows7Desktop-Debug\debug\Test1.exe exited with code -1073741819
```

Every time. I start a new project, I do whatever, but I get that error. Now, I have also run in debug mode. I get this error:

```
The inferior stopped because it received a signal from the Operating System.
Signal name: SIGSEGV
Signal meaning: Segmentation fault
```

The offending file is `qatomici386.h` at line 132, and the specific function is `QBasicAtomicInt::deref` which states:

```
inline bool QBasicAtomicInt::deref()
{
        unsigned char ret;
    asm volatile("lock\n"
                 "decl %0\n"
                 "setne %1"
                 : "=m" (_q_value), "=qm" (ret)
                 : "m" (_q_value)
    -->          : "memory");
    return ret != 0;
}
```

I have arrowed line 132.
I am running a 64 bit machine, but I believe I installed a 32 bit MinGW... but honestly I don't even know if that is the real problem, let alone how to fix it if it is. I am very new to C++ and Qt.

As requested, here is my code:
mainwindow.cpp:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

main.cpp:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Test1.pro:

```
#-------------------------------------------------
#
# Project created by QtCreator 2012-12-17T23:06:31
#
#-------------------------------------------------

QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = Test1
TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES += main.cpp\
        mainwindow.cpp

HEADERS  += mainwindow.h

FORMS    += mainwindow.ui
```

mainwindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

If anything else is needed, just ask.

Here is the complete debugging backtrace:

```
0   QBasicAtomicInt::deref  qatomic_i386.h  132 0x402774    
1   QString::~QString   qstring.h   880 0x402805    
2   WinMain@16  qtmain_win.cpp  93  0x401eab    
3   main            0x402e6b
```

Update: I ran the example `toy clock`, and it worked fine. However, when I ran the `calculator form`, it resulted in the exact same error. I notice that the `calculator form` is in the normal project form: it has a `.pro`, and Header, Sources, and Forms folders. The `toy clock` on the other hand just has a `.qmlproject` file and a qml folder. It also fails at the same location with the same backtrace. I don't actually know much about any of these things, but hopefully it will help find a solution.

Comment: You can safely assume that Qt code is reasonably error-free. More useful would be **your** code.

Comment: Heh. Ok, but as I said it is just the default.

Comment: Choose a debug build, run your application in a debugger, and look at the complete backtrace/post it here.

Comment: I did post the final error, I guess I can add the rest of the backtrace...

Comment: Your code seems to work fine for me on Qt 4.8.3 (OSX 10.6.8). It must be your environment.

Comment: Any idea how to fix the environment?

Comment: Make a complete clean+rebuild of the project. If this does not work, delete all `moc_` files from the build path and clean+rebuild again

Comment: Done and done. And started from scratch and reinstalled MinGW, Qt 4.8.4, and Qt Creator. Nothin'

Comment: So, I have installed Linux and it works fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've been having the same problem, after just installing this whole environment.

I have been searching around, and there appears to be a bug on the Qt bug tracker at:
https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTCREATORBUG-7653

From the page:

> There are multile binary incompatible versions of mingw. You need to use the same[1] mingw >version for both qt and your program. Which means either compiling qt yourself with that >mingw version or using the same as what was used for compiling the binary qt packages.(I'm not sure but that might be a newer than ftp://ftp.qt.nokia.com/misc/MinGW-gcc440_1.zip )
>
> [1] same in the sense of ABI

Comment: I found the same bug report, so I checked to make sure that I only have one MinGW installation, and the Qt Creator is only using it. I do, and it is. D:

Comment: Ah, yeah. I read that as I had to either compile the Qt version myself, or switch to the mingw version that was used to compile the release I downloaded.

Comment: Oh. I... may have misread that, and it is quite possibly the solution. At some point I will have to try and recompile Qt with my version and see if it works. Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: So yeah, that worked. It is just that building Qt is one of the biggest pains in the neck I have ever had to deal with

Comment: I ran into horrible problems attempting recompilation and am sticking with linux for now. What a pain.

Answer (score 1):

Comparing some of my (inherited) Qt apps and this [Qt tutorial](http://sector.ynet.sk/qt4-tutorial/my-first-qt-gui-application.html), I notice a difference in the initializer for `MainWindow`.  It may just be a convention, but these sources show `MainWindow` directly inheriting the Ui class, and then a direct call to `setupUi(this);`.

So, this would retool your `mainwindow.cpp` to:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent)
{
    setupUi(this);
}
```

You didn't include `mainwindow.h`, but the class definition should look like:

```
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow, private Ui::MainWindow
{
//...
```

Comment: The OP is using one of [the multiple ways to use a designing UI file](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/designer-using-a-ui-file.html) Your example here is the inheritance approach. The OP is doing "Using a Pointer Member Variable"

Comment: I included the .h. This is their default template, without me adding anything to it that is not running. I would like to assume that their template code is alright, but that means the problem lies in something more obnoxious and obscure.

Answer (score 0):

I also have the same issue, just restart windows and the problem was solved, really strange but it works for me.

Hoep this help !!